# How to mark a job as failed when interrupted from the console with Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I wroted a DB migration program using Spring Batch that I run from the command line. The job repository is persisted using H2 and it works as expected but when I interrupt it using <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, the instance of the job is marked as finished with error and accordingly non-restartable. How can I tell the Spring Batch framework that mark the job as failed and then restartable? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** My problem is that when I use the `-restart` option, the CommandLineJobRunner class does not find any failed job to restart, because it is marked as finished with error when it is stopped with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. Hope this clarify a little.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are running this from the command line.  See this [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html).  In particular, check out the `-restart` parameter.